# .NET XSD.exe misses attribute group references

Tags: xml, xsd

This is a part of my XSD:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="matches">
  <xs:attribute name="min-matches" type="positiveInt" default="1" use="optional" />
  <xs:attribute name="max-matches" type="positiveIntUnbounded" default="1" use="optional" />
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:attributeGroup name="pathAndMatches">
  <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="matches" />
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

When I use .NET FX's `xsd.exe` it does only generate a `path` property when I reference `pathAndMatches` in an element. Why doesn't it generate properties for min/max matches? Is my XSD invalid? xsd.exe doesn't show any errors or warnings.

Comment: I don't know the tool, but I notice those attributes are `optional`, that might explain why they aren't generated by default.

Comment: If I put the two attributes directly into the pathAndMatches attribute group it works. So I don't think it's the optional attribute. Note: I want to split the matches from pathAndMatches for reuse in another attribute group.

Comment: are `positiveInt` and `positiveIntUnbounded` defined in your xsd?

Comment: Yes. As I said before, if I immediately put the min-matches / max-matches attribute into the pathAndMatches without the ref inbetween it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately nested attribute groups are not supported by xsd.exe.  See the following note from the docs:

> The  element cannot be nested in another
>    element. Nested instances will be ignored by the
>   Xsd.exe tool.

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/484632e7.aspx

[Liquid XML Data Binder](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-data-binder) supports them. If your projects not to big you can generate it using the free community edition.

Comment: Thanks for the docs! Was already fearing something like that :-(